# Error add new block into block Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, controllers, page-layouts

I'm using Magento 2.3.4 and t tried to append a block to another block like this in my controller:

```
            $category_list_subcategories = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('promotion.view.subcategories.wrapper');
            $catIdx = 0;
            if ($category_list_subcategories){
                foreach ($childCategories as $childCategory){
                    $catIdx++;
                    $subcategoryBlock = $this->layoutFactory->create()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\View\Subcategory');
                    $childCategory = $this->categoryFactory->create()
                        ->setStoreId($this->helper->getStoreId())
                        ->load($childCategory->getId());
                    if (!$this->categoryHelper->canShow($childCategory)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $subcategoryBlock->setData('current_category', $childCategory);
                    $subcategoryBlock->setData('cat_index', $catIdx);

                    $subcategoryBlock->setData('parent_landing_is_hide_lang', $category->getData('landing_is_hide_lang'));
                    $subcategoryBlock->setData('parent_landing_sort_by_price', $category->getData('landing_sort_by_price'));
                    $subcategoryBlock->setData('parent_landing_sort_by_name', $category->getData('landing_sort_by_name'));

                    $category_list_subcategories->append($subcategoryBlock); //this line causes an error

                }
            }
```

my layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\View\Index" name="promotion.view.categories" template="Vendor_Module::view/index.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="promotion.view.subcategories.wrapper"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

but when i tried to access the page i got this following error:

> Exception #0 (OutOfBoundsException): The element with the
>   "view\subcategory_0" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again.

Comment: Your block file  change this id $catIdx = 0;

Comment: @MohitPatel yes i tried to add a block per subcategory into another block

Comment: you chnage $catIdx = 0; value

Comment: @MohitPatel Still same error

Comment: can you do var_dump for $category_list_subcategories ?